# Spring integration jdbc array update query spel expression

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jdbc, spring-el

I'm trying to create an 'update-query' for my `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` given following workflow :

1. Select 500 records of type A from database
2. Update 1 row in another table with the values of the last record read ( the one at position 500 )

But i'm unable to sort it out, as been trying to use spring-el to find the value.

By debugging, i reached `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` `executeUpdateQuery` method,

```
void executeUpdateQuery(Object obj) {
        SqlParameterSource updateParameterSource = this.sqlParameterSourceFactory.createParameterSource(obj);
        this.jdbcOperations.update(this.updateSql, updateParameterSource);
    }
```

where `Object obj` is an ArrayList of 500 records of type A

This is my best match :

```
UPDATE LAST_EVENT_READ SET SEQUENCE=:#root[499].sequence, EVENT_DATE=:#[499].eventDate
```

Can anyone help me ?

P.S. Type A has sequence and eventDate attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a custom `SqlParameterSourceFactory` and already don't rely on the SpEL:

```
public class CustomSqlParameterSourceFactory implements SqlParameterSourceFactory {

    @Override
    public SqlParameterSource createParameterSource(Object input) {
        List<?> objects = (List<?>) input;
        return new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(objects.get(objects.size() - 1));
    }

}
```

Inject this into the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.setUpdateSqlParameterSourceFactory()` and already use simple properties in the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE LAST_EVENT_READ SET SEQUENCE=:sequence, EVENT_DATE=:eventDate
```